# Local Flow Partitioning for Faster Edge Connectivity: implementation

Tags: python, c++, graph, connectivity

I'm doing a research for a university exam and I'm searching the web for an implementation of the algorithm shown in the paper "Local Flow Partitioning for Faster Edge Connectivity" by Monika Henzinger, Satish Rao and Di Wang (2019) that computes the minimum cut in a simple and undirected graph, but I cannot find one. As I'm searching this implementation for the purpose of an experimental comparison against an other (that I have to implement yet) I was wondering if anyone can help me! I tried many github repository or libraries like NetworkX or NetworKit but nothing yet. Anyone can tell me something helpful? Any language is accepted but it will be great if it was in C++ but also Python is ok.
Many thanks!

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Tarjan's Algorithm finds the cut vertices in an undirected graphs.  These are the vertices that, if any one is removed, then the graph is split into an increased number of unconnected components.

You can find a C++ implementation at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Cuts